# Prevent abuse of sendmail for spam

Tags: sendmail, spam, abuse

In web servers that host many websites there is always the possibility of a hacked site being abused in order to send spam mails with some kind of php mailer bot.

In my case sendmail is configured for mailing in the php.ini of each site, and I am wondering if there is a way that I can prevent this kind of problem (like aplying rules for maximum mails send from a certain domain etc.).

Dirty hacks (scripted solutions) are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

off the top of my head:

- Disable `mail()` inside of `PHP` and allow it per site.
- Enforce `SMTP` `authorization` and refuse non authorized users.
- Handle (throttle) it on `MTA` side (`postfix`, `sendmail`, etc).

Comment: Disabling the command seems like an unfair thing to do. There are many websites that send out mails using contact forms etc.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google i found this on Stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226699/how-to-monitor-postfix-mta-status

There is a script on the second answer. That might help you out. This way no interference on functionality and you will be kept in the loop is there is something wrong.